# How to use HTML DOM to easily use input on a sudoku board

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have a sudoku board made using a table with 9  and 81  each with an id of its index in a 2d array as id="y-x".

```
<table class="board">
    <tr><td id="0-0"></td><td id="0-1"></td><td id="0-2"></td><td id="0-3"></td><td id="0-4"></td><td id="0-5"></td><td id="0-6"></td><td id="0-7"></td><td id="0-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="1-0"></td><td id="1-1"></td><td id="1-2"></td><td id="1-3"></td><td id="1-4"></td><td id="1-5"></td><td id="1-6"></td><td id="1-7"></td><td id="1-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="2-0"></td><td id="2-1"></td><td id="2-2"></td><td id="2-3"></td><td id="2-4"></td><td id="2-5"></td><td id="2-6"></td><td id="2-7"></td><td id="2-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="3-0"></td><td id="3-1"></td><td id="3-2"></td><td id="3-3"></td><td id="3-4"></td><td id="3-5"></td><td id="3-6"></td><td id="3-7"></td><td id="3-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="4-0"></td><td id="4-1"></td><td id="4-2"></td><td id="4-3"></td><td id="4-4"></td><td id="4-5"></td><td id="4-6"></td><td id="4-7"></td><td id="4-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="5-0"></td><td id="5-1"></td><td id="5-2"></td><td id="5-3"></td><td id="5-4"></td><td id="5-5"></td><td id="5-6"></td><td id="5-7"></td><td id="5-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="6-0"></td><td id="6-1"></td><td id="6-2"></td><td id="6-3"></td><td id="6-4"></td><td id="6-5"></td><td id="6-6"></td><td id="6-7"></td><td id="6-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="7-0"></td><td id="7-1"></td><td id="7-2"></td><td id="7-3"></td><td id="7-4"></td><td id="7-5"></td><td id="7-6"></td><td id="7-7"></td><td id="7-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="8-0"></td><td id="8-1"></td><td id="8-2"></td><td id="8-3"></td><td id="8-4"></td><td id="8-5"></td><td id="8-6"></td><td id="8-7"></td><td id="8-8"></td></tr>
</table>
```

My problem is: Using vanilla javascript, how do I detect a click on each  and then waiting for keyboard or mouse input (having numbers on the screen) and adding that to the innerHTML without 81 lines of code and possibly more for the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to only add an event listener on the table itself.

Events expose  an event object in the handler callback. For user events there is a `target` which is the actual element the event occurred on. So in your case you can check that the target is a `<td>`

I only show you  very simple click event to get you started, not to create all the functionality you need

For your next step you could add a class to the element to change it's background style and you could also make all the elements `contenteditable` to allow users to write in them. There are other events you can research for `focus` and `blur` to track changes

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table.board');

table.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target.matches('td')){
     console.clear()
     console.log('Cell clicked', event.target.id)
  }
})
```

```css
td { width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<table class="board">
    <tr><td id="0-0"></td><td id="0-1"></td><td id="0-2"></td><td id="0-3"></td><td id="0-4"></td><td id="0-5"></td><td id="0-6"></td><td id="0-7"></td><td id="0-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="1-0"></td><td id="1-1"></td><td id="1-2"></td><td id="1-3"></td><td id="1-4"></td><td id="1-5"></td><td id="1-6"></td><td id="1-7"></td><td id="1-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="2-0"></td><td id="2-1"></td><td id="2-2"></td><td id="2-3"></td><td id="2-4"></td><td id="2-5"></td><td id="2-6"></td><td id="2-7"></td><td id="2-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="3-0"></td><td id="3-1"></td><td id="3-2"></td><td id="3-3"></td><td id="3-4"></td><td id="3-5"></td><td id="3-6"></td><td id="3-7"></td><td id="3-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="4-0"></td><td id="4-1"></td><td id="4-2"></td><td id="4-3"></td><td id="4-4"></td><td id="4-5"></td><td id="4-6"></td><td id="4-7"></td><td id="4-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="5-0"></td><td id="5-1"></td><td id="5-2"></td><td id="5-3"></td><td id="5-4"></td><td id="5-5"></td><td id="5-6"></td><td id="5-7"></td><td id="5-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="6-0"></td><td id="6-1"></td><td id="6-2"></td><td id="6-3"></td><td id="6-4"></td><td id="6-5"></td><td id="6-6"></td><td id="6-7"></td><td id="6-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="7-0"></td><td id="7-1"></td><td id="7-2"></td><td id="7-3"></td><td id="7-4"></td><td id="7-5"></td><td id="7-6"></td><td id="7-7"></td><td id="7-8"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="8-0"></td><td id="8-1"></td><td id="8-2"></td><td id="8-3"></td><td id="8-4"></td><td id="8-5"></td><td id="8-6"></td><td id="8-7"></td><td id="8-8"></td></tr>
</table>
```